# Colorization of XML tags in JEditorPane

Tags: java, xml, swing

I am showing an XML file in JEditorPane.
How can I colorize the XML tags in JEditorPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addmit you to use a highlighter. You can use it like that:

```
jeditorpane1.getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, end, 
             new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red));
```

Than you just need to create a method which finds out alle xml tags and set the start end points and the color.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use a JEditorPane, you can just highlight the text you want. Alternatively, you can create an HTML (3.2) document or an RTF document that represents the XML with the appropriate color highlighting. (A better solution might be to use a JTextPane with a StyledDocument.)

However, it's not all that easy identifying the XML tags themselves. For that, you might consider a third-party solution. There are also a number of XML editors around, some of them open source. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984497/wysiwyg-xml-editor-java) for some leads, or do a web search for *"java xml editor"*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [XMLEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html) to highlight all the xml parts. It also allows to fold xml sections.